# identify a Douglas Adams-ish short story about a failed attempt to communicate with aliens that ends with an anticlimactic sentence

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

When I was a teenager I read a story about scientists who received radio signals (or something like that) of extraterrestrial origin but were unable to decode them. After many years of receiving these signals and sending "responses" in their direction, trying to establish a dialogue but without success, Earth finally receives a message from the mysterious origin that it manages to decipher, which is something like: sorry, we are not talking to you (or maybe 'we're talking to the guy behind you', I don't remember precisely).

I've already looked for short stories by Douglas Adams and similar authors but haven't found any clues. Maybe it's just an excerpt from a book and not a short story.

Edit:I must have read this between 2009 and 2011 and I read it in Portuguese but it may have been translated from English. I can't remember where I read it but I THINK it was in a book.

Comment: Given its age it's almost certainly not the answer, but the plot resembles "Qu'est-ce qu'ils peuvent bien nous dire?" ("What do you want to say to us?") by Tristan Bernard from 1894 (!), in which Earth picks up messages from Mars. It end with the line "We're not talking to you, we're talking to Saturn."